# How can I prevent the other user from using the D drive

Tags: windows, windows-10, shared-folders, user-folders

I am the administrator on my PC. There is another local account on this PC. I just want to know, if I wish that the other will not be able to view D and E drive, then what should I do? How can I prevent the other user from using the D drive?

I have tried the "stop sharing"  from the computer management, but the other user still can open the D drive.

I am on Windows 10 Pro OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Right-click the file
2. Properties
3. Security
4. Modify
5. Add or remove user rights. If needed, remove anyone but you.

People will still be able to *see* D and E drives, but they won't be able to *access* them.

By the way, "Stop sharing" will only stop your computer from sharing these drives on the network, it does not have any effect locally.

Comment: This works but it has to apply the parameters to all files that you wish to block the access. Is there a way to block access to a full disc at once?

Comment: @Puck in the dialogs to change permissions, there is an option that applies your modifications to all of the directory contents recursively. It's called something like "apply settings to all children" or "Replace settings on children from what can inherited from this object".

Comment: I am aware of that, but it still has to apply this to all children. The problem in my case is that there is a tremendous amount of files on the disc I want to limit access and it would take days to finish. Therefore, I am looking to completely block access to a disc without having to apply to all files.