# Creating multiple users in windows

Tags: windows-8.1, user-accounts

When I create multiple users in ubuntu it's much more convienient. In ubuntu, we get seperate hard drives management for all users created. One user cannot access the files of the other user, unless s/he is  the superuser. But, in windows, it seems like all  the files are accessible, only the desktop is cleared up and the programs are defaulted. It's not really convienient if other users created can access your files.

This is the case now for me, I have created a new user,  and password protected my account, but, say my brother accesses  my PC,  and signs in into  the account  created for him, then he accesses my files in D: from his account.

Is this  really the case  with windows,  or is it that I'm missing  something that  can be customized? Or if it is how to get the behaviour like ubuntu? I'm currently using windows 8.1.

Comment: Also this: https://superuser.com/questions/1099386/how-can-i-prevent-the-other-user-from-using-the-d-drive

Comment: And this: https://superuser.com/questions/1115595/windows-10-how-do-i-lock-limit-another-users-access-to-my-folders

Answer (score 1):

Afaik you can always set the access rights to every file and directory in windows. When you right click the file or folder you can see properties. Then you can see the security tab where you can define which persons can access the file or directory. When you are lucky you are able to lock out yourself out of that file or directory.

Comment: "you are lucky you are able to lock out yourself out of  that file or directory" ? What does that mean? And not only is it not permitted in ubuntu,  it's actually isolated as a separate directory for the user,  all  the accounts are  like files on a computer.

Comment: If you deny the access to everybody, then you can really deny the access to yourself as well. Imagine you aren't the admin. Then you go to the security and deny full control to authenticated users or users in general. Leaving the access to the administrators only, so that you can delete the file afterwards. When you save the changes you will not be able to open that file anymore. Only as an admin.

Comment: @niceboy-programmer if the answer wasn't helpful, please give me some feedback, if yes, please mark it as resolved.