# Windows 10 creating a new user account

Tags: windows-10

Is it possible to create a second user account in Windows 10 that can only access C drive, and the other drives are not visible to that new account ?

Comment: In general, no.  You would have to set up specific permissions to all other users for the other drives and not include this new user. You can do it without setting up a new account if you so desire.

Comment: To restrict users with specified permission on the drive and folders will help to prevent them to modify or change the drive but still be visible:How can I prevent the other user from using the D drive
https://superuser.com/questions/1099386/how-can-i-prevent-the-other-user-from-using-the-d-drive

Comment: Hi, If I remove the user to the Hard Drive by 1- Right-click 
2- Properties
3- Security
4- Modify
5- Add or remove user rights. Would the Hard Drive be completely invisible to the remove user ?